# loopback HasAndBelongsToMany relation id property in created table

Tags: node.js, database, loopback

when I have a HasAndBelongsToMany relation between to tables, automigration creates a new table with and id property, how can I prevent to create that?

For example:

### Assembly

id: number
name: string

### Part

id: number
name: string

### AssemblyParts (automatic created table)

id: number
assemblyId: number
partId: number

I don't what the id property in the AssemblyParts table.

Comment: This is rather unclear, what do you have so far and what is it that you're exactly asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can, this is a generic solution and some databases enforce/encourage to have an ID in binding tables for unique rows. This is not a major problem for you, is it?